# GridView Converting Current Page into DataSet/DatTable

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GridView current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447125/gridview-current-page)

I have a GridView ,I enabled Paging.

I want to convert the current page of gridview into DataTable.Is there any extension method or techniques available to convert the current page contents of a gridview into DataTable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447125/gridview-current-page

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[GridView current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447125/gridview-current-page)